# Spring UmlStateMachineModelFactory can't be used with DefaultStateMachineService?

Tags: java, uml, spring-statemachine

I want to use Eclipse Papyrus to generate the state machine model, but when I want to create an instance of a StateMachine at runtime, the created bean of `ObjectStateMachineFactory` doesn`t have the UML Machine Model set.

If I configure it manually like this:

```
new ObjectStateMachineFactory<>(umlStateMachineModelFactory.build())
```

the method getStateMachine() from `AbstractStateMachineFactory` tries to acces configurationData, which is null in the `DefaultStateMachineModel` created by `UmlStateMachineModelFactory`

Do I have to configure it manually or there is a misconfiguration I don´t see?

these are my dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-statemachine.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring-statemachine.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-statemachine-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-statemachine-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-statemachine-data-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-statemachine-uml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-statemachine-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My code:

```
    @Bean
    public StateMachineService<String, String> stateMachineService(
            StateMachineFactory<String, String> machineFactory,
            StateMachineRuntimePersister<String, String, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister) {
        //this doesn´t inject the uml model in the machine factory
        return new DefaultStateMachineService<>(machineFactory, stateMachineRuntimePersister);
        //this throws null pointer when trying to access configuration data
        //ObjectStateMachineFactory<String, String> machineFactory = new ObjectStateMachineFactory<>(machineModelFactory.build());
        //return new DefaultStateMachineService<>(machineFactory, stateMachineRuntimePersister);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've configured it, together with JPA, where "uml/sm.uml" is path to your UML:

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
public class UMLStateMachineConfiguration extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {

    @Configuration
    public static class JpaPersisterConfig {

        @Bean
        public StateMachineRuntimePersister<String, String, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister(
                JpaStateMachineRepository jpaStateMachineRepository) {
            return new JpaPersistingStateMachineInterceptor<>(jpaStateMachineRepository);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private StateMachineRuntimePersister<String, String, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister;

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineModelConfigurer<String, String> model) throws Exception {
        model
                .withModel()
                .factory(modelFactory());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<String, String> config)
            throws Exception {
        config
                .withPersistence()
                .runtimePersister(stateMachineRuntimePersister);
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineModelFactory<String, String> modelFactory() {
        UmlStateMachineModelFactory factory = new UmlStateMachineModelFactory(
                "uml/sm.uml");
        factory.setStateMachineComponentResolver(stateMachineComponentResolver());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineComponentResolver<String, String> stateMachineComponentResolver() {
        DefaultStateMachineComponentResolver<String, String> resolver = new DefaultStateMachineComponentResolver<>();
        resolver.registerAction("myAction", myAction());
        resolver.registerGuard("myGuard", myGuard());
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineService<String, String> stateMachineService(
            StateMachineFactory<String, String> stateMachineFactory,
            StateMachineRuntimePersister<String, String, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister) {
        return new DefaultStateMachineService<>(stateMachineFactory, stateMachineRuntimePersister);
    }

    public Action<String, String> myAction() {
        return new Action<String, String>() {

            @Override
            public void execute(StateContext<String, String> context) {
                System.out.println("in E1");
            }
        };
    }

    public Guard<String, String> myGuard() {
        return new Guard<String, String>() {

            @Override
            public boolean evaluate(StateContext<String, String> context) {
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```